# Gradle resolutionStrategy does not override version as expected

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have defined a dependency in a sub-project, e.g.:

```
testCompile(
  "org.springframework:spring-test:4.3.7-RELEASE",
)
```

And my main build.gradle overrides resolutionStrategy:

```
subprojects {

  configurations {
    compileClasspath.transitive = false
    testCompileClasspath.transitive = false

    all*.resolutionStrategy {
      eachDependency { details ->
        def requested = details.requested

        switch (requested.group) {
           case 'org.springframework':
             details.useVersion '4.3.7-RELEASE'
             break
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But dependencies are resolved as (snippet):

```
+--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.3.7.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.7.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.7.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.7.RELEASE
|         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.7.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.7.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.7.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.7.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.7.RELEASE -> 4.3.0.RC2
|    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.0.RC2 -> 4.3.7.RELEASE
```

Notice the `org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.7.RELEASE -> 4.3.0.RC2`

Why does this happen?

I'm using Gradle 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
all.resolutionStrategy {
  eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
      details.useVersion '4.3.7-RELEASE'
    }
  }
}
```

Taken from https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html